# How can i display users' post count in 'post sayı' column?

Tags: laravel, post, count

how can i display my users' posts count in "post sayı" column? ...........

Here is my users.blade:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('users')

<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col">Ad</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
        <th scope="col">Səlahiyyət</th>
        <th scope="col">Post sayı</th>
        <th scope="col">Düzəlişlər</th>


    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($users as $user  )
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{$user->id}}</th>
        <h4 class="media-heading"> <td><a href="posts/{{$user->id}}" class="anchor-username">{{$user->name}} </a></td></h4>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->getRoles['name']}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->getPost['user_id']}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{route('delete',['id'=>$user->id])}}">Sil</a><br><a href="{{route('edit',['id'=>$user->id])}}">Düzəlt</a></td>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

@endsection
```

and here is my controller

```
public function index($id)
{
    $posts = Post::where('user_id', $id)->get();

    return view('posts', compact('posts'));
}
```

My User model:

```
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Role', 'id', 'role_id');
}

public function getPost()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Post', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: i h've tried this but doesn't work.

Comment: please also show your user model so we can see your relationships

Comment: <td>{{$user->getPost['user_id']->count()}}</td> i tried that solution but it give me error " Call to a member function count() on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\site\resources\views\users.blade.php)" i update and add user model

Comment: Welcome to SO ... based on these relationships the user can only have 0 or 1 Post, so you just want to know if they have one or not?

Comment: As @lagbox already said, if you use a hasOne() relationship, you have at max 1 post, maybe you need to use a  `hasMany()` relationship?

Answer (score 1):

```
  // Controller
  public function index()
    {
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 2) {
            $posts = Auth::user()->posts()->latest()->get();
            return view('user.post.index', compact('posts'));
        }
        else{ return view('login');
        }
    }
// View
<span class="btn btn-warning sm">{{ $posts->count() }}</span>
// User Model
 public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
// Post Model
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have this in your controller: `$posts = Post::where('user_id', $id)->get();`

You could do this in your view: `<td>{{ $posts->count() }}</td>`

However, I would suggest using Eloquent relationships as [Md.Azizur Rahman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11215386/md-azizur-rahman) suggested.

1. Your model should have a `hasMany` relationship in the `getPost` (should renamed to `getPosts` or just `posts` IMO).

   ```
   public function posts()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
   }
   ```
2. Also, make sure that your Post Model contains a `belongsTo` relationship to the User Model while you are at it!

   ```
   public function user()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
   }
   ```
3. Then you can replace the following from your controller:

   ```
   $posts = Post::where('user_id', $id)->get();
   return view('posts', compact('posts'));
   ```

   with:

   ```
   return view('posts');
   ```
4. Finally, in the view it would be as follow: `<td>{{ $user->posts->count() }}</td>` *( posts is the name of the relationship)

   Or: `<td>{{ auth()->user()->posts->count() }}</td>` for the authenticated user (I think you won't be using this since I think you're doing an admin CRUD kinda thing in the your example).

Hope it help!